# How Can I #define "elif" as "else if", in C++?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I wanted to have `elif` as a macro for `else if` by means of c++ Preprocessor

So that instead of writing like :-

```cpp
if (something)
{
    // Do something
}
else if (something else)
{
    // Do something else
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

I could just write like :-

```cpp
if (something)
{
    // Do something
}
elif (something else)
{
    // Do something else
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

**This is what i tried :-**

```
#define elif "else if"
```

*But MinGW-w64 is Showing Error :-*

```
error: expression cannot be used as a function
```

Help Please !?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? `else if` was too readable by C programmers so you need to find a way to make your code less readable, or...?

Comment: @Lundin I think `elif` looks better that `else if` (coming from python background). Also my programs are mostly private

Comment: Paul Ogilvie & @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes thanks that worked,  i have never used #define before, just saw some youtuber using quotes so I used too,

Comment: I would *strongly* advise *not* doing this, even though you are the only person who will read your code. It can be very hard to unlearn bad habits, and writing code that only you understand is a very bad habit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#define` preprocessing directive does not use quotation marks to delimit its replacement text. To define `elif` to be replaced by `else if`, simply use:

```
#define elif else if
```

That said, this would generally be regarded as a bad idea. C programmers become accustomed to the normal keywords that affect program control, and using customized keywords will confuse many people.

Comment: thanks, i have never used #define before, just saw some youtuber using quotes so I used too

Answer (score 4):

Yes, C and C++ allows all manner of crazy things, such as inventing your own secret language using macros. Doing so turns your code very hard to read for C and C++ programmers, because they know C and C++ but they don't know your secret macro language.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define elif else if
#define if(...) if(0)

int main() 
{
  int my_own_macro_language=1;
  int good_idea=1;

  if (my_own_macro_language == good_idea)
    puts("Lets invent our own macro language!");
  elif (!good_idea)
    puts("Ok so not a good idea but lets do it anyway!");
  elif (I really want to write strange macros, please please please)
    puts("Ok since you asked nicely!");
  else
    puts("Bad idea, lets stick with C and drop the macros.");
}
```

Output:

```
Bad idea, lets stick with C and drop the macros.
```

Comment: r/ProgrammingHumor